# Using NDEigensystem with Periodic Boundary Conditions in 2D

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

What is the correct method for specifying periodic boundary conditions when solving for the eigensystem of a PDE in a rectangular region? The following implementation does not work.

```
 d=1;
 v1 = d{0, 1}; v2 = d{1, 0};
 reg = Parallelogram[{0, 0}, {v1, v2}];

 NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], u[x, 0] == u[x + d, 0], 
 u[0, y] == u[0, y + d]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do that:

```
eig = NDEigensystem[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]
   , PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], y == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, 4]
```

A visual inspection:

```
Plot3D[#[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg] & /@ eig[[2]]
```

[image]

And a more formal inspections:

```
Plot[#[x, 0] - #[x, 1], {x, 0, 1}] & /@ eig[[2]]
```

[image]

You can also check this:

```
Plot[#[0, y] - #[1, y], {y, 0, 1}] & /@ eig[[2]]
```